# Implement the realization of function in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a function

```
def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1|+|a2
```

It need to implement the realization

The result must be:

```
foo[Test](Test(1), Test(2)) // Test(3)
```

I wrote some code in IDEA worksheet, but it is not compile

```
case class Test(num: Int)

object Test {
  implicit val test = new Writer[Test] {
    def write(v1: Test, v2: Test) = {
      Test(v1.num + v2.num)
    }
  }
}

trait Writer[A] {
  def write(v1: A, v2: A): A
}


implicit class someT[A](a1: A) {

  def |+|(a2: A)(implicit writer: Writer[A]) = {
    writer.write(a1, a2)
  }
}

def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1|+|a2

foo[Test](Test(1), Test(2))
```

the output error is:

```
Error:(32, 34) could not find implicit value for parameter writer: A$A213.this.Writer[A]
def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1|+|a2
                            ^
Error:(32, 34) not enough arguments for method |+|: (implicit writer: A$A213.this.Writer[A])A.
Unspecified value parameter writer.
def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1|+|a2
                            ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the implicit `Writer[A]` required on `foo`:

```
def foo[A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit writer: Writer[A])
```

Or if you prefer context bounds:

```
def foo[A : Writer](a1: A, a2: A)
```

Now, the compiler can in turn see that `|+|` has a `Writer[A]` in scope.